# Remove smallest number in JS Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a number array [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1] and want to remove the smallest number in the list. But somehow my IF statement gets skipped.

I checked and by itself "numbers[i + 1]" and "numbers[i]" do work, but "numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]" doesn't...

```js
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  var smallestNumberKEY = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= numbers.lenths; i++) {
    if (numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) {
      smallestNumberKEY = i + 1;
    }
  }
  numbers.splice(smallestNumberKEY, 1);
  return numbers;
}

document.write(removeSmallest([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]));
```

Comment: `lenths` ? When you fix this typo - your code will have 2 problems with reading values out of an array boundary: 1. The `number.length` item does not exist in the array 2. The `number.length + 1` item does not exist either.

Comment: Once you've corrected length you will also be looking beyond the end of the array.

Comment: wow such a studied mistake... Thank you everyone

Comment: The code also won't work if the smallest number is the first one.

Comment: numbers[i] AND numbers[i + 1] will NOT work, if i = numbers.length;

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo in your code, array doesn't have `lenths` property

```js
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  var smallestNumberKEY = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
    if (numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) {
        smallestNumberKEY = i + 1;
        numbers.splice(smallestNumberKEY, 1);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}

document.write(removeSmallest([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]));
```

But your algorithm wont work for another array, e.g `[5, 3, 1, 4, 1]`, it will remove a value `3` too.

You can find the min value with `Math.min` function and then filter an array

```
function removeSmallest(arr) {
    var min = Math.min(...arr);
    return arr.filter(e => e != min);
}
```

Comment: Regarding this code where you use Math.min(),this code won't work for cases where we have an array with all the same elements in it. For e.g. Cases with array like: [3, 3, 3,3]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

```js
function removeSmallest(arr) {
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  return arr.filter((e) => {return e != min});
}

console.log(removeSmallest([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]))
```

Comment: **WARNING**: `O(n^2)`

Comment: maybe you can find out `min` first and then filter on it later?

Comment: if there is 2 (or more ) min values it will filter more than once

Comment: @zerkms no, this is O(2n), n^2 would be a loop in a loop. This is just two loops side-by-side.

Comment: @kzh check the time of my comment and the history of the edits of the answer. The initial version of the answer I addressed was `O(n^2)` now it is linear indeed.

Comment: @zerkms can you remove the now invalid comment, then?

Comment: Could you not use the spread operator instead of `.apply()`? Also, this fails if all the values in an array are equal; eg `[1,1,1,1,1]`

Answer (score 3):

Short one liner. If the smallest value exist multiple times it will only remove ONE. This may or may not be what you want.

```
const result = [6,1,3,1].sort().filter((_,i) => i) // result = [1,3,6]
```

It works by sorting and then creating a new array from the items where indeces are truthy(anything but 0)

Comment: Actually, This is the best solution to the question asked.
Can you please explain how the filter index is working, because you didn't mention any index number show how it is removing value at index 0?

Comment: @SimranSingh the `0` in the index is treated as `false` and gets filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

another solution with `splice` and `indexOf`:

```js
array = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1];

function replace(arr){
  arr = arr.slice(); //copy the array
  arr.splice( arr.indexOf(Math.min.apply(null, arr)),1)
  return arr;
  }

document.write( replace(array) ,'<br> original array : ', array)
```

edit :  making a copy of the array will avoid the original array from being modified

Comment: if there is a reason for DV it would be constructive to give feedback

Comment: You're only removing one of the 1s.

Comment: @Andy the OP says `remove the smallest number` not `numbers` ; the requirement should be to remove 1 item ... (and if you read his code that is what he's trying to do)

Comment: The smallest number is 1. The requirement is be to remove all 1s. Take a look at the other answers.

Comment: @Andy if I had thought other answers were completely correct I wouldn't have answered..

Comment: OK, take a look at the OP's original code. You can tell from that.

Comment: @Andy to me it looks like he's splicing once and returning the array, but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

"Short" solution using `Array.forEach` and `Array.splice` methods:

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
    var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
    numbers.forEach((v, k, arr) => v !== min || arr.splice(k,1));
    return numbers;
}

console.log(removeSmallest([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1]));  // [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal with a **single loop** of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and **without** `Math.min`.

The algorithm sets in the first loop `min` with the value of the element and returns an empty array, because the actual element is the smallest value and the result set should not contain the smallest value.

The next loop can have

- a value smaller than `min`, then assign `a` to `min` and return a copy of the original array until the previous element, because a new minimum is found and all other previous elements are greater than the actual value and belongs to the result array.
- a value greater then `min`, then the actual value is pushed to the result set.
- a value equal to `min`, then the vaue is skipped.

```js
'use strict';

var removeSmallest = function () {
    var min;
    return function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (!i || a < min) {
            min = a;
            return aa.slice(0, i);
        }
        if (a > min) {
            r.push(a);
        }
        return r;
    }
}();

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify([2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1].reduce(removeSmallest, []), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `this.min` will create global variable `min` in non-strict mode, which is not good. Also this code won't work in strict mode, because `this` will be undefined inside `removeSmallest` function.

Comment: @YuriyYakym, thanks for pointing that problem. now it should work without polluting the global space.

Answer (score 0):

I like this oneliner: `list.filter(function(n) { return n != Math.min.apply( Math, list ) })`

check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/rz2n4rsd/1/

```
function remove_smallest(list) {
    return list.filter(function(n) { return n != Math.min.apply( Math, list ) })
}

var list = [2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1]
console.log(list) // [2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1]

list = remove_smallest(list)
console.log(list) // [2, 1, 4, 5, 1]

list = remove_smallest(list)
console.log(list) // [2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Quite slow since you find min() for each item in the list

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this but I needed a solution that did not mutate the input array `numbers` and ran in O(n) time. If that's what you're looking for, try this one:

```
const removeSmallest = (numbers) => {
  const minValIndex = numbers.reduce((finalIndex, currentVal, currentIndex, array) => {
      return array[currentIndex] <= array[finalIndex] ? currentIndex : finalIndex
    }, 0)
  return numbers.slice(0, minValIndex).concat(numbers.slice(minValIndex + 1))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumOfPaiars(ints){
         var array = [];
         var min = Math.min(...ints)
         console.log(min)

 for(var i=0;i<ints.length;i++){
  if(ints[i]>min){
    array.push(ints[i])
  }
 }

return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to remove a single instance of the smallest value (which was my use-case, not clear from the op).

```
arr.sort().shift()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that is work properly but is not accepted from codewars:

```
let numbers = [5, 3, 2, 1, 4];

numbers.sort(function numbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});

const firstElement = numbers.shift();
```

Comment: Maybe OP does not want to sort.

Comment: The exercise was to sort the number ascending and to take out the smallest one.