# How do i return new array with removing one of the elements based on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove the smallest number in the array without changing the sort of the array and return a new array without the smallest number, If there are multiple elements with the same value, remove the one with a lower index.

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  return Math.min(...numbers)
}

removeSmallest([5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1]) // output is 1 , but I want output [5, 3, 2, 4,1 ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove smallest number in JS Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225314/remove-smallest-number-in-js-array)

Comment: What if there are multiple numbers in an array and smallest also.